# How to make chrome/firefox able to run parent.frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am working on a old web not supporting chrome/firefox.
One problem is the code can be run on IE but not chrome/firefox.

```
 put 'parent.frames("snscont").location.href="../../../../../fts/main/account/INITIAL.html"';
```

On Chrome,it indicated **uncaught type error: parent.frame is not a function**.
Any jquery or modern code can make this supported chrome/firefox?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to fallback `parent.frames` to the old IE behavior:

```
function isFunction(obj) {
  return !!(obj && obj.constructor && obj.call && obj.apply);
}

if (parent.frames && !isFunction(parent.frames)) {
  var originParentFrames = parent.frames;
  parent.frames = function(name) {
    return originParentFrames[name];
  };
}
```

For your questions in comment:

**Why use parent?**

Without context of your code, it's hard to answer this question. Basically, `parent` references the parent of the current window or subframe, if it is invoked on a window that does not have a parent, then it references to itself. You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent for more detail (Thanks to @jeetendra's answer).

I guess your code run in an iframe? If that is true, then `parent.frames(B)` in frame `A` is a good way to reference iframe B from iframe A.

**Is parent an object?**

Yes, `parent` is an object attached on `window`. You can run `typeof parent` to get the result `object`.

**What is snscont? Is it a parameter for function frames()?**

`snscont` is the name of your iframe. `parent.frames()` use name to reference an iframe object. So, yes, it is passed as a parameter.

**What does the latter part starting form href means? Is it redirecting to the page listed at the end?**

Yes, the `...location.href="..."` statement makes the iframe display another URL. But I don't think `redirect` is the accurate word here.

Comment: I am quite new to parent.sth this kind of coding.Can you explain a little bit about `parent.frames("snscont").location.href="../../../../../fts/main/account/INITIAL.html"';`

1.Why use parent?Is parent an object?
2.What is snscont?Is it a parameter for function frames()?
3.What does the latter part starting form href means?Is it redirecting to the page listed at the end.
Thanks

Comment: @KenyKeny your further questions have been answered. Please check.

Comment: I inserted your function code before the error part. The web works like a charm. Thanks for answering.

But 
What is `!!`? Isn't that a double negation meaning nothing?

Comment: `!!x` in javascript does not mean nothing, it converts `x` to boolean value.